# Issue on Geting Var from Postabck

Tags: php, mysql

I need to place a php code to get Variables form postback url ( http://example.com?r=joe&s=19
and then placed it in my mysql database. May I know what I missed?

Thanks in advance.

```
$DBHost = "localhost";
$DBUser = "useridofmysql";
$DBPassword = "passofmysql";
$DBDatabase = "databaseofmysql";

$user = @$_GET['r'];
$age = @$_GET['s'];


$mymysql = mysql_connect($DBHost,$DBUser,$DBPassword) or die;
mysql_select_db($DBDatabase, $mymysql) or die("Could not select database");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO `postback`(username, age)VALUES('$user', '$age')");

mysql_close($mymysql);
```

Comment: Are you encountering any error?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens? Aslo, don't use mysql, look at mysqli or PDO please.

Comment: Why are you using @ symbol?

Comment: What you are doing is very risky, receive parameters by querystring, persist them in the database and do not sanitize. However try to remove the @ before the GET or echo the result of the variables to make sure that the parameters are coming.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `mysql_*` deprecated functions. Why do you put `@` in front of yours variable assignment? You're hiding errors if there's some during your debug.

Also, try to do this, to see if the error doesn't come from the SQL statement:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `postback`(username, age)VALUES('$user', '$age')") or exit(mysql_error());
```

It'll display you the SQL error if there's one (But, you really should move to `PDO`, or at least `mysqli_`)